# Credentials for Webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I wanted to write credential for web services (I am using-VS 2008,Asp.Net Framework 3.5,Windows 2003 Standard Edition,SQL Server) like this

```
      private Credentials credentials;
```

But i am getting error to this line that the type or namespace name 'Credentials' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have used

```
      using ExtentrixWS;
```

Still i am getting '**are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**'
Regards,

Comment: Is Credentials a class you have defined in your web service? If so have you made sure it is public? Also if it is a class in your web service, if you are using WCF make sure you have created it as a DataContract, or the web reference wont generate it on the client side.

Comment: @stuartmclark, he has clearly mentioned its an asp.net application and also its not a class which is written inside his program, its the class got from the service namespace used.

Comment: @skk I understand that he is writing an ASP.NET application I was asking if he had written the Web Service.

Comment: I have written the Web Service and could call it from my asp Application. Its working.But now I want to put some credentials for accessing the WebService.

Answer (score 0):

You should not only add the "using ExtentrixWS" but also you should add the [relavent dll to the references of the project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceConsumer.aspx?msg=3076787&display=Mobile). Then only the services of ExtentrixWS will be referrenced to your project.

Comment: which relavant dll is  required?

Comment: @Nick, did you referred to the link I had given in the answer?